# Concatenate two unsigned chars to be one uint16_t

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to right something that will take two unsigned chars and grab the 4 lower bits of one and concatenate that on to the front of the other 8 bits.

```
x = 01234567
y = 23458901
doBitWise = 890101234567
```

Is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
unsigned char x = someNumber; 
unsigned char y = someNumber;
uint16_t result = (x & (1 << 4) - 1) | (y);
```

But that gives me a warning saying the result is going to be bigger than a uint16_t? Am I missing something?

Comment: What compiler?  Can you paste the full, complete warning or error?  Your code with `clang -Wall -Wextra` gives no warnings, apart from if I actually try to put the value `23458901` into a char as you have done (what's going on there, by the way??).

Comment: Is that result actually supposed to correspond to the "doBitWise" result, given the inputs in the example?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Just thought it would be easier to visualize what I was saying with more than just 1's and 0's. The warning is `Values of type 'int' may not fit into the receiver type 'uint16_t'`

Comment: The result will be larger than `uint16_t` because the maximum value for `uint16_t` is 65535.

Comment: Thats what Im wanting to do, just take the last 4 bits of y and put it with all of x. Making a 12 bit result

Comment: @Shane the warning is bogus, the result will always fit.  The compiler is warning for assignment of `int` to `uint16_t` without bothering to see if in fact the value of the `int` is guaranteed to be in range for the `uint16_t` (which it is in your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is because there is arithmetic conversions happening in the expression `uint16_t result = (x & (1 << 4) - 1) | (y);`. Here `(1<<4)-1` will have type int, and x is of type `unsigned char`, according to the rules of conversion, the result will be of type `int`, which does not fit into a `uint16_t` on your platform.

Reference, c11 std 6.3.1.8 on Usual arithmetic conversions:

> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
>     all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
>      the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
>      operand with signed integer type.

To get the 4 lower bit of `x`, use `x & 0xF`. Also cast it to `uint16_t` before applying the shift operation,

```
uint16_t result = (uint16_t)(((x & 0xF) << 8) | y);
```

This will put the lower 4 bit of x ahead of y. The expression you used will or lower 4 bits of x with y, it does not do what you want.

Comment: What does the cast of x to `uint16_t` do? Doesn't that arg get promoted to `int` anyway because of the integer promotions rule?

Comment: @PaulHankin it's redundant in this exact case, but if you're unsure it's perhaps better to err on the safe side. You need to be wary against promotion to signed type which then encounters signed overflow on shifting, or unexpected behaviour when other types are promoted to match

Comment: The whole premise of this answer is that integer promotions are causing trouble in the original code, and that by inserting the cast it can make a difference. But in fact, the "fixed" code has exactly the same integer promotions going on, and the expression on the right-hand-side of the = is still an int.

Comment: @PaulHankin the original code is wrong anyway (it never attempts to left-shift the 4 bits after the mask) so it's not really a basis for comparison

Comment: I mistakenly typed the cast to x, I meant to cast the result to uint16_t, not x.

Comment: There's two questions: why does the compiler warn, and what's the right code. I agree the code given in the answer is right, but the explanations about the compiler warning don't add up -- the given code also has type `int`, just the same as the original code.

Comment: `(uint16_t)(x & 0xF)` will evaluate to an `uint16_t`. it will fit into the result, so there is no warning.

Comment: I commented on the compiler warning under the original question (tl;dr: it's a bug)

Comment: @fluter but that's not your code: `((uint16_t)x & 0xF)` evaluates to an `int`, as does `((uint16_t)(x & 0xF) << 8) | y` (because of integer promotions). I agree with M.M. that the compiler warning is a bug.

Comment: @fluter Admitting an error in the comments is fine, but unnecessary. Fixing the answer is what's important. I fixed it for you, see if you agree, and make any changes as needed.

Comment: BTW, the way I read the question, it's `y` that needs to be masked and shifted.

Comment: All of this is far too complicated, you'd just have to force the literals to be `unsigned`. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Thats what Im wanting to do, just take the last 4 bits of y and put it with all of x. Making a 12 bit result

```
x = 01234567
y = 23458901
doBitWise = 890101234567
```

In that case, you should left shift the **y** by 8, and mask the front 4 bits:

```
uint16_t result = (((unsigned short)y << 8) & 0xF00) | x; //result will be casted to uint16_t
```

Note: be careful of the operator precedence. + comes before <<, thus parentheses is needed

Note 2: to prevent undefined behavior when int is 16-bit and to ensure that the result of y << 8 will be having at least 16-bit, explicit casting to unsigned short is added (since y is originally unsigned char). Besides, the inserting of x is using bitwise OR operator |.

Comment: Can a uint16_t be promoted to a 16-bit int?

Comment: @PaulHankin It is (forcefully) casted to 16-bit int if the int is 16-bit. But on the operation, if we specify the type of data to be unsigned short, then the promotion should at least be to a data type which can handle unsigned short value, not to 16-bit int

Comment: In `y << 8`, when `y` is `uint16_t` and `int` is 16 bit, then `y` is promoted to `unsigned int`, not `int`, because `int` "cannot represent all values of the original type". So MM's comment (now deleted) was a mistake and your code was, in fact, fine in the first place.

Comment: @PaulHankin `y` is `unsigned char`

Comment: @PaulHankin ah, I get it. So y << 8 alone will be (in the first place) unsigned int. But if the int is 8-bit, then wouldn't the explicit casting to unsigned short be necessary?

Comment: There is no 8-bit int -- MAX_INT is always at least 32767. `y << 8` will always be `int`. `((unsigned short)y << 8)` will be `int` if `int` can represent all values of `unsigned short`, and `unsigned int` otherwise. What a mess :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said the problem here is that before doing arithmetic, narrow integer types are converted to `int`, a signed type. But the solution to that should be much simpler, just force unsigned arithmetic:

```
uint16_t result = (x & (1U << 4) - 1U) | (y);
```

Here, the literals are `unsigned`, so is then the result of the `<<`, `&`, `-` and then `|` operators. This is because these operators, if presented with `int` and `unsigned` always do a conversion of the `int` part to `unsigned`.

For the final conversion from `unsigned` to `uint16_t`, this always well defined by modulo arithmetic and no sane compiler should complain about this.